# Digitpot sequential power up

Tags: digital-potentiometer

I am using an [MCP41HV51](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/20005207A-259170.pdf) digipot IC to convert digital signals from an STM32 board to analog voltage. The datasheet states that the control circuit of the IC need to be powered up first, then the analog circuit to be powered after it in order to maintain the last wiper position before power off. I was wondering, is there a way to achieve this power up sequence using only passive components?

Comment: I would think that entirely depends upon what the analog circuit consists of. What does it consist of in your case?

Comment: Just a motor driver that receiver an analog signal to set the speed.

Comment: Is the motor turned on by the STM32? Or is it expected to start on power-up? If turned on by the STM32, then just a) initialize the digipot via STM32, then b) start up the motor. If the motor driver is not controlled by the STM32, then if you provide a schematic, we may be able to add STM32 control to it.

Comment: yes the motor is controlled by the STM32
it is a good idea to initialize the digipot before powering the motor and it would solve my problem thanks, but out curiosity is there an analog circuit that can achieve this powe-on delay?

Comment: you don't need any extra components. Just initialize the digipot, then start the motor driver. What would the extra passive components do?

Comment: Yes I understand that, you solved my problem thanks, I am asking for just general knowledge nothing else.